# How to scrape a form that requires field validation by user?

Tags: forms, vba, excel, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape prices from this site:
https://www.pensketruckrental.com/quote/start.html

I can easily enter the form data, and I can activate the "Get A Quote" button and click it.

What I can't seem to do is get the form data to submit using a web scraper (I'm just doing it in VBA). When I input text using the scraper, the button remains grayed out, and even making a `.click` call on the button just displays errors on the form telling you not to leave the fields blank. Apparently it only recognizes data when you use an input device?

The code for one of the required fields, `pickupLocation`, is the following when I enter it manually (and thus the button works and the form can be submitted):

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    id="pickUpLocation" 
    name="pickUpLocation" 
    class="penskeValidateField penskeGoogleTypeAhead penskeInlineError ng-isolate-scope ng-touched ng-focused ng-dirty ng-valid-penske-err_loc_empty_sa ng-valid ng-valid-parse ng-valid-required"        
    aria-invalid="false" 
    aria-required="false" 
    country="rentalEntryCtrl.formItems.country" 
    penske-validate-field="pickuplocation" 
    required="" 
    autocompelete="off" 
    data-penske-placeholder="rentalEntryCtrl.activePlaceHolders.pickUpLocation" 
    ng-model="rentalEntryCtrl.formItems.pickupLocationSearchCriteria.address" 
    autocomplete="off">
```

And when I enter the data automatically using my scraper the tag & attributes read as follows:

```
<input 
    type="text"
    id="pickUpLocation"
    name="pickUpLocation" 
    class="penskeValidateField penskeGoogleTypeAhead penskeInlineError ng-pristine ng-isolate-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required placeholder ng-touched"  
    aria-invalid="true" 
    aria-required="true"  
    country="rentalEntryCtrl.formItems.country"
    penske-validate-field="pickuplocation"
    required=""  
    autocomplete="off"  
    data-penske-placeholder="rentalEntryCtrl.activePlaceHolders.pickUpLocation"
    ng-model="rentalEntryCtrl.formItems.pickupLocationSearchCriteria.address" 
    autocompelete="off">
```

So of course I tried to copy the fields in the first code block into the second code block using `setAttribute()`, but even though I could change the attributes, I still couldn't get the form to submit properly.

I've looked at others that have dealt with something somewhat similar with autocorrect; their solutions have involved looking at the header and responses and just using the straight XHR to loop through the autocomplete queries, but the pricing information I'm scraping comes after several pages of form submissions, so that's not an option here.

I'm stuck I think; any ideas on how to populate the form and click the button/submit via my scraper?

Comment: Can you share the website? One thing I noticed is the `aria-invalid` attribute went from false to true using the automation. You might try switching this value and see what happens.

Comment: Dang it, I meant to include the web site. Edited. So I did change all the attributes to match the ones in the validated form, but it still showed the same error message.

Comment: So I got part of this working. As it turns out you need to call the change event like this: `ie.document.parentWindow.ExecScript ("$('#puDateOneWay').change()")` for each entry (each ID) into the form. Doing this makes the submit button "ungreyed" out, but it doesn't allow me to click it. I tried submitting the form and clicking the button, nothing worked. I think you need to call an event/javascript function on the page, just not sure which one.

Comment: @RyanWildry very helpful; thank you. Where are you looking to find these scripts?

Comment: These are using jQuery. You can get started with jQuery here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Comment: @RyanWildry awesome; you're just using jQuery's `.change()` method then to try to alter the way the site handles input, right?

Comment: It seems like the site needs a change event to process the input to the field.