# Excel VBA: How do I trigger an input field validation on a HTML webpage

Tags: jquery, html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to use VBA to automate input to a webpage, https://www.cpf.gov.sg/eSvc/Web/Schemes/LifePayoutEstimator/LifePayoutEstimator. I have written the following VBA code that fills in the various input fields, as an example for what I'm trying to achieve.

```
Sub SubmitEstimatorForm()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://www.cpf.gov.sg/eSvc/Web/Schemes/LifePayoutEstimator/LifePayoutEstimator"
    Do While ie.READYSTATE <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set htmldoc = ie.document
    Set htmldisclaimercheck = htmldoc.getElementbyid("is-disclaimer-checked")
    Set htmlmaleradio = htmldoc.getElementbyid("radioMale")
    Set htmlfemaleradio = htmldoc.getElementbyid("radioFemale")
    Set htmldobfield = htmldoc.getElementbyid("DateOfBirth")
    Set htmlrabalfield = htmldoc.getElementbyid("RetirementAccountBalance_display")
    Set htmlnextbutton = htmldoc.getElementbyid("btnCalculate")

    htmldisclaimercheck.Click
    htmlmaleradio.Click
    htmldobfield.Value = "01/01/1960"
    htmlrabalfield.Value = "50000.00"
    htmlnextbutton.Click

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, there appears to be a additional validation for the "Current Retirement Account Balance" field that triggers if I key the same "50000.00" into the webpage manually, but does not do so when the field is populated programmatically via VBA. The lack of this validation causes an error when trying to submit the form, i.e. clicking the next button.

[image: Error message]

I've tried various means of triggering the validation through FireEvents, using onclick, onchange, onfocus etc but so far have not been successful.

After doing some research, I believe that the approach to solving this should probably be via executing the underlying javascript/jquery, and have found a similar question at [How to scrape a form that requires field validation by user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688674/how-to-scrape-a-form-that-requires-field-validation-by-user), however despite numerous attempts with .execScript() I have still been unable to achieve what I need. What I am struggling with is finding the appropriate script or jquery to execute, due to unfamiliarity with javascript/jquery and the DOM explorer.

Would appreciate suggestions or tips on how to proceed, whether via the above approach or through other alternatives. Thank you!

Comment: If the goal is to learn VBA then keep it up! However if the goal to simply automate your CPF calculations like the site does, this is a *terrible* way to do it.  All the site is doing is a simple calculation, and with the effort you'll need to go through to scrape the number from the website, you'd be far better off too do the calculation yourself in Excel.  (as it's intended to be for!)  There are several pages with details about the calculations and some of the have ready-to-use downloadable Excel workbooks.  [Here's the first one I found.](https://www.advanced-excel.com/calculate-cpf.html)

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the suggestion, agree that using Excel is more efficient. I'd still like to seek a solution to the original programming problem though - you can take it that I'm trying to learn VBA, yes:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following. You need to `focus` before `click`.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SubmitEstimatorForm()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://www.cpf.gov.sg/eSvc/Web/Schemes/LifePayoutEstimator/LifePayoutEstimator"

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Dim htmldoc As HTMLDocument, htmldisclaimercheck As Object, htmlmaleradio As Object
    Dim htmlfemaleradio As Object, htmldobfield As Object, htmlrabalfield As Object
    Dim htmlnextbutton As Object

    Set htmldoc = ie.document
    Set htmldisclaimercheck = htmldoc.getElementById("is-disclaimer-checked")
    Set htmlmaleradio = htmldoc.getElementById("radioMale")
    Set htmlfemaleradio = htmldoc.getElementById("radioFemale")
    Set htmldobfield = htmldoc.getElementById("DateOfBirth")
    Set htmlrabalfield = htmldoc.getElementById("RetirementAccountBalance_display")
    Set htmlnextbutton = htmldoc.getElementById("btnCalculate")

    htmldisclaimercheck.Click
    htmlmaleradio.Click

    htmldobfield.Value = "01/01/1960"

    With htmlrabalfield
        .Focus
        .Value = "50000.00"
    End With

    With htmlnextbutton
        .Focus
        .Click
    End With

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    'other code

End Sub
```